# Count hours of all events within a specific calendar

Tags: macos, calendar, calendar.app

Is there a way to get the number of hours that have been tallied in a given month for an iCal calendar?

If so, how?

I have been considering just tallying my freelance hours in excel or similar.

I'm on OSX 10.5.8.

Totally open to using a quick and easy (and free) app to do this task.  One that allows me to put in multiple wages per freelance project would be ideal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nowadays you can use Apple Shortcuts app for this. Here's what I'm playing with now:

1. Find Calendar Events
2. Get Details of Calendar Events (choose "Duration")
3. Calculate Statistics (choose "sum")
4. Calculate expression ("sum / 3600") to convert from seconds to hours

https://www.icloud.com/shortcuts/aeb42865b33947d9aef5115ecee25270

[image: screenshot of the shortcut]

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [this](http://www.stevenriggs.com/Site/TimeTable.html) app. It seems to be able to filter and count hours from the iCal database. Yes it costs, but there is a 14day trial!

Alternatively, there is a post [here](http://compsigh.com/article/1) that discusses using an applescript application to do exactly what you are after. There are some sample apps attached at the bottom :)

Comment: I am fine with scripting up a solution using AppleScript.  Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: Both links are broken now

Answer (score 1):

I found a sort of workaround. This guy invented a hours calculator for Google Calendar. What I did was I shared my Outlook (MS Office 365 Calendar) with my gmail account so it would open it. Then used that online app to count the hours for me. Here is the site: www.google-calendar-hours.com

Answer (score 0):

Warning: A bit of shameless self-promotion ahead!

I've been searching for the exact same thing. There use to be an apple script called [iCal Duration](http://www.kanzaki.com/docs/ical/duration.html) that did this job pretty well, but unfortunately it breaks since upgrade to Maverics.

Since my Apple script foo is non-existing, I've created my own JS app that works similarly, by pasting all the desired events directly from iCal: http://icalligator.changeset.hr/

So hopefully it will be useful to someone else, too.